# MassTransit not sending messages - RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have an issue with MassTransit not sending messages with the following code - this is a port from our Azure Service Bus code which works fine. The examples in GitHub populate the Queue - Starbucks example, so my infrastructure is working.

Can anyone please suggest why this is not sending messages? I have created both the queue and exchange, and tried without.

The console app prints out the expected results.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            IBusControl busControl = CreateBus();

            TaskUtil.Await(() => busControl.StartAsync());

            List<Task> tList = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var t = Send(busControl);
                tList.Add(t);
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tList.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("done!");
        }

        private static async Task Send(IBusControl busControl)
        {
            var endpoint = await busControl.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/test"));

            Console.WriteLine("Sending");

            await endpoint.Send(new SomethingHappenedMessage()
            {
                What = "Stuff",
                When = DateTime.Now
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Sent");
        }

        static IBusControl CreateBus()
        {
            return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x => x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost"), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            }));
        }
}

 public interface SomethingHappened
    {
        string What { get; }
        DateTime When { get; }
    }

    public class SomethingHappenedMessage : SomethingHappened
    {
        public string What { get; set; }
        public DateTime When { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Is the `test` exchange bound to the `test` queue?

Comment: I would add stopping the bus at the end to ensure all open pipelines finish executing.

Comment: Chris, binding the queue worked, thank you - I am new to RabbitMQ. This doesn't explain why the Starbucks sample worked out of the box though - I think this is MassTransit 2.0 though. I'll mark it correct if you answer. Thanks again.

Comment: The Starbucks sample adds consumers, which creates the queue bindings - your sender above doesn't create a receive endpoint - so no consumers.

Comment: KnowHoper Can you please explain how you did the exchange ↔ queue binding in the above code? I'm having the same issue. If the Consumer isn't set up, then the publish doesn't work. No idea what happens with the message. @ChrisPatterson

Comment: Nothing is created until you register a consumer.

Comment: @KnowHoper Indeed, but what I want to achieve is to save the message in RabbitMQ when publishing a message without an active consumer (I mean, the situation when the queue is not yet created). This is also the question in your original post isn't it?

Comment: First of all, this is for `Send`, not `Publish` - and it should be your last choice, to be honest. Start your receiveEndpoints before your producers come online. It isn't that complicated. Don't try to make it hard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you send messages with MassTransit using RabbitMQ, by default the bindings for the queue are not created. It is assumed that a receive endpoint in a service will create the queue and related bindings.

To ensure that the queue and bindings exist when sending a message, you can modify the endpoint address to include some additional query string parameters as shown below:

```
rabbitmq://localhost/vhost/exchange_name?bind=true&queue=queue_name
```

In the case of a receive endpoint, the exchange name and queue name are the same.